# Homestead migrate mysql problems

Tags: laravel, database, homestead

I've a problem with my laravel project. I can only use php artisan migrate by vagrant ssh.
In normal terminal it shows me a connection error with database.

This is my env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=db_corsi
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Comment: please provide the error text or a screenshot of it.

Comment: please cross check the port.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, if you have time mark an answer as useful/accepted if it helped you solve your problem. This is in order to help others too.

Answer (score 1):

change port `DB_PORT=33060` to `DB_PORT=3306`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not an issue because vagrant is VM so you need to access it to can run the artisan migrate